# Question about Salem's integral equation reformulation of Riemann hypothesis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, analytic-number-theory, integral-equations, riemann-hypothesis

Consider an integral equation:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-\sigma y}f(y)}{e^{e^{x-y}}+1}dy=0$$, where $\sigma\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$

Salem proved that this equation has no bounded solution other than trivial $f(y)=0$ iff Riemann hypothesis is true.

Suppose we want to construct a counterexample, that is , a non zero function $f(y)$ satisfying the integral equation. My question is should $f(y)$ be independent of both the parameters $x$ and $\sigma$ present in the kernel of the integral equation? In other words, we need to construct a function $f(y)$ which works for all $x$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: You have a horrendous misspelling in the title.

Comment: I cannot count how often this poor guy was called "Reimann" :) An interesting equivalence although it won't make the conjecture easier.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4354500) to a related question provides some insight.

Comment: @Peter  your comment reminds me of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433899/why-is-lebesgue-so-often-spelled-lebesque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual equivalence is the following: one fixes $\sigma >1/2$; then the existence of $\phi$ (nontrivial) bounded, measurable function of one real variable (say $y$ though of course the name of the integration variable is irrelevant as long as it's not $x$ or $\sigma$ eg $f(y)=y$ or whatever), solving the above **for all** $x$ real is equivalent (by Wiener famous Tauberian theorem and a little functional analysis and measure theory, noting that by duality, the existence of $\phi$ is essentially equivalent to the fact that the linear space generated by the translates, $K_{\sigma}(x-y), x$ arbitrary, regarded as functions of $y$, are not dense in $L^{1}(\mathbb R(y))$) to the fact that the Fourier transform of the kernel $$K_{\sigma}(u)=\frac{u^{\sigma}}{e^{e^u}+1}$$ vanishes at $\sigma+it$ for some $t$ real; but this transform is essentially (up to constants) $\Gamma(\sigma+it)\eta(\sigma+it)$ where $\eta$ is the usual Dirichlet eta obtained from the alternating zeta (so $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$).

In particular the existence of such a $\phi$ is equivalent to the fact that $\eta$ hence $\zeta$ has a zero with abscissa $\sigma$ so to the negation of RH.

The simple details above and Wiener's Theorem are presented for example in Broughan's reference book on Equivalents of the RH volume $2$ chapter $8$

Comment: I don't know if your comment answers my actual question. Suppose a non-trivial bounded measurable solution exists say, f(y). Should f(y)
 be independent of both the parameters x
 and $\sigma$ present in the kernel of the integral equation?

Comment: $f$ is just a function of one variable but it needs to satisfy the above equation for a fixed $\sigma$ and all $x$ - edited the text to make it clear; the name of the variable is irrelevant since we integrate against it (as long as is not $x$ or $\sigma$ of course)

Comment: @Conrad should your "nucleus" be "kernel"?

Comment: Yes - will correct; thk you